# Check whether a TextView is completely filled with text

Tags: android, textview

In my application I am loading some text from database into a `TextView`. Is there any way to detect(set a flag) when the `TextView` is fully filled with text.
`TextView` has attributes

```
layout_width = "fill_parent"
layout_height ="fill_parent"
```

I was searching for a solution and found none. Can someone suggest me a logic.

Comment: It depends from what you understand by "TextView is fully filled with text" - is this when the `TextView`'s text fills the whole width of the device ? If yes, what happens if someone rotates the device on the side?

Comment: @g00dy Yes when text fills the full width and height. Since I am using only portrait orientation screen rotation is not a problem.

Comment: What would be your concern? `TextView` can hold as much text as you want (Sure there is a limit but it is negligible for most cases). If you host your `TextView` in a `Scrollbar`, users can browse all the text, no matter how long it is.

Comment: Ok, first thing you want to do, since the text size is determining everything - you want the text font to be Courrier New or Derivates of Courrier font (why - because this font has a fixed and the same width for each character in it). Then determine the width of everything that is not text through the width of the screen and on the level of the textview (borders etc.) then subtract the width of those parts from the width of the screen. After that calculate the width of a character and see how many can be fitted to the visible part of the screen. Can't be any more exhaustive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your goal is to present text in a `ViewPager`I would recommend you rethink your design.

The problem with your approach is that you can never be sure what screen resolution people will have when opening the application or if they want to zoom. If you implement what you want to implement then you either need to reduce functionality so users cannot zoom or change the layout. This is a bad practice in my opinion. In fact, I believe the [Android Developers Design Principles](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) might even have to say something about that. I would recommend you always offer functionality with your application that the users are likely to expect.

Should you still want to go ahead you need to consider that when users zoom, the amount of text the screen is able to display will change. Not only will this lead to quite some computation overhead as a zoom is likely a continuous event, but it will also mean that the users might see some jerking around of text. Again, unexpected behaviour.

What I would recommend is that you either compute the amount of text you want to display beforehand for the given display and then stick with it, leaving people free to zoom at their leisure, or you issue an `Intent` [(Documentation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to an application that implements the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am redesigning it using a ScrollView to display the TextView.

Comment: @eric-tobias Don't many reading apps use this viewpager approach? Like kindle, readability, aldiko

Comment: Hard to say for sure but they are likely using efficient designs. Therefore, they are bound to use at least something similar. It is always a good practice to stick to well established designs and patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Try to calculate the TextView width and the actual text width and compare. You can calculate the actual text width by this function:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
float text_width = p.measureText("your_text");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` by default I believe has overflow set. You need to set restrictions. Do something like: `android:maxLength="20"` then create a statement to see if the size of the `TextView` is 20

Comment: I mean when the entire screen is filled with text I need to detect that.

Comment: That would depend on your resolution. You would have to do some math and hard-code some variables to account for borders and the orientation. I think you might need to rethink why you need to know this.

Comment: @EricTobias Actually I am developing a Bible application. I want to fill the entire page with text and if the screen is full break the text and use a ViewPager to fill further pages.